# Edge detection on dim edges using Python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, contour, edge-detection

I want to find dim edges using Python.

Input images (100 X 100) :

[image]

[image]

[image]

It consists of several horizontal boards: top, middle, bottom.

I want to find middle board bounding box like:

[image]

I used several edge detection methods (prewitt_x, sobel_x, cv2.findContours) but cannot detect well.

Because edge btw black region and board region is dim.

How can I find bounding box like red box?

Code below is example using prewitt_x and cv2.findContours:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('my_dir/my_img.bmp',0)

# prewitts_x
kernelx = np.array([[1,1,1],[0,0,0],[-1,-1,-1]])
img_prewittx = cv2.filter2D(img, -1, kernelx)
img_prewittx_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_prewittx, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imwrite('my_outdir/my_outimg.bmp',img_prewittx)

# cv2.findContours
image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img_prewittx_gray, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
rects = [cv2.boundingRect(cnt) for cnt in contours]
print(rects)
```

In fact, I don't want to use slower one like Canny detector.

Help me :)

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your problem.  What do you mean by several boards?  What exactly do you want to find?

Anyway, your image seems very noise.  Can't you change colors or apply a noise reduction filter?

Comment: You could blur the image with a huge kernel and then apply a spatial closing operation. You will not get the smallest cut but at least you could get the different regions. When I understand the problem it is independent of the x coordinate. Now you can search for the longest white are in both of the identified sets and adjust the y value.

Comment: @fredguth Each image, they have total 5 part. From up to down : gray-black-gray-black-gray. The gray part is what I mean "borad". What you mean "change color"? It's like using HSV filter?

Comment: @MaxKrappmann Do you mean a huge kernel is like [[10,10,10],[0,0,0],[10,10,10]] rather than [[1,1,1],[0,0,0],[1,1,1]] ?

Comment: No you have to increase your size of the filter. https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d13/tutorial_py_filtering.html

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion:

- use a simple edge detection filter such as Prewitt
- project horizontally (sum of the pixels in every row)
- analyze the resulting profile to detect the regions of low/high activity and delimit the desired slabs.

[image]

You can also try the maximum along rows instead of the sum.

But don't expect miracles, this is a hard problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comment :) I'll try it